# mxnet ndarray iterator for C++

Tags: c++, iterator, mxnet

I would like to train a simple classifier in C++, very much in the fashion of the [C++ mnist example](http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/c%2B%2B/basics.html), where however my data is not stored on the HD but already loaded to the memory, say to an mxnet NDArray. In Python for this purpose one has the handy `NDArrayIter`, c.f. [Module tutorial](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/basic/module.html).

Is there such an NDArray iterator for C++?

Browsing through the code I found that all possible `MXDataIter`'s can be read out from `MXListDataIters` and `MXDataIterGetIterInfo`:

```
#include "mxnet-cpp/io.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace mxnet::cpp;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Context ctx = Context::cpu();  // Use CPU

  mx_uint num_data_iter_creators;
  DataIterCreator *data_iter_creators = nullptr;

  int r = MXListDataIters(&num_data_iter_creators, &data_iter_creators);
  CHECK_EQ(r, 0);
  cout << "num_data_iter_creators = " << num_data_iter_creators << endl;
  //output: num_data_iter_creators = 8

  const char *name;
  const char *description;
  mx_uint num_args;
  const char **arg_names;
  const char **arg_type_infos;
  const char **arg_descriptions;

  for (mx_uint i = 0; i < num_data_iter_creators; i++) {
      r = MXDataIterGetIterInfo(data_iter_creators[i], &name, &description,
                                &num_args, &arg_names, &arg_type_infos,
                                &arg_descriptions);
      CHECK_EQ(r, 0);
      cout << " i: " << i << ", name: " << name << endl;
  }

  MXNotifyShutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

which yields the eight `MXDataIter()`'s:

```
num_data_iter_creators = 8
 i: 0, name: ImageDetRecordIter
 i: 1, name: CSVIter
 i: 2, name: ImageRecordIter_v1
 i: 3, name: ImageRecordUInt8Iter_v1
 i: 4, name: MNISTIter
 i: 5, name: ImageRecordIter
 i: 6, name: ImageRecordUInt8Iter
 i: 7, name: LibSVMIter
```

So it appears to me that for C++ there is no NDArray iterator and that the easiest solution would be to write my data to csv-files only to then load it again into a `MXDataIter(CSVIter)`. Another possibility would be to manually split the data into batch NDArray's and feed these into the training, but this also feels clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no NDArrayIter in C++ package.

But I would say that it shouldn't be hard to implement, if you really need one. Take a look how it is implemented in Python, and maybe you can contribute back to the community with your implementation for C++ - https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/fe5b56e419d454dc8f42f0307f53ced133804ca7/python/mxnet/io.py#L544

Comment: This is obviously not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for answering.